# Error 664 Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

por favor ayuda. Ya le hice los cambios a Laravel tales como:

```
/App/Providers/AppService.Provider.php
```

agregar lo siguiente:

```
   public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

También realiza las siguientes modificaciones:

```
/config/database.php/
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix_indexes' => true,
```

Tengo instalado en Laragon: PHP 7.2.19 phpMyAdmin 4.8.5.... y al hacer esta migración me sigue saliendo el error

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('teacher_id');
    $table->foreign('teacher_id')->references('id')->on('teachers');
    $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    $table->unsignedInteger('level_id');
    $table->foreign('level_id')->references('id')->on('levels');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->string('slug')->nullable();
    $table->string('picture')->nullable();
    $table->enum('status' , [
            \App\courses::PUBLISHED,
            \App\courses::PENDING,
            \App\courses::REJECTED,
             ]);
       $table->boolean('previus_approved')->default(false);
       $table->boolean('previus_rejected')->default(false);
        // $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

He hecho las pruebas y sin los siguientes datos puedo hacer la migración sin problemas, pero si los vuelvo activar me muestra el error 664

```
 $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
 $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
 $table->unsignedInteger('level_id');
 $table->foreign('level_id')->references('id')->on('levels');
```

Amigos muchas graciaspor su gran ayuda....

---

Este es el error que me sale:

```
`Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]:
```

General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint 
(SQL: alter tablecoursesadd constraint
courses_category_id_foreign
foreign key`(`category_id`)`
referencescategories`(`id`))
      at`C:\laragon\www\plataforma\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
660|     // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error`
        661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
        662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
        663|         catch (Exception $e) {

> 664|             throw new QueryException(
>           665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
>           666|             );
>           667|         }

Comment: Podrías por favor editar y colocar el mensaje de error completo por favor?

Comment: ¿Nos podrías indicar en que orden ejecutas las migraciones?, parece ser ese el error

Comment: **yo lo unico que hago es escribir en la terminal: php artisan:migrate:fresh --seed**

Comment: Si pero el mensaje de error te esta indicando un fallo en la creación de las llaves foráneas y esto se puede deber a los tipos de datos empleados en estas mismas o el orden en el que estan creados los archivos de migraciones.

Comment: ah ok el orden de creación son:
teacher
students
courses
levels
categories
subcriptions
coments
requirements
goals
table_course_student
reviews

Comment: Pues el error por lo que veo es que estas creando una tabla courses que ocupa una llave foránea llamada `category_id` apuntando a la tabla categories, pero esa tabla la creas hasta después de la tabla `courses`, entonces ahí el error, la llave foránea no tiene a donde conectarse pues esa tabla: `categories` aún no existe, debería ser primero categories y luego courses

Comment: Por otro lado el error que nos muestras no tiene nada que ver con agregar **Schema::defaultStringLength(191);**

Comment: voy a probrar @Aprendiz, sos un genio muchas gracias

Comment: esto en si no es un error de Laravel, sino de SQL por un orden incorrecto de declaración

Answer (score 1):

El error no esta relacionado con Laravel, sino con SQL y en específico con MySQL que te indica un fallo en la construcción de las sentencias SQL que recibe para formar las tablas.

Tu indicas tener una migración que ocupa crear estas llaves foráneas:

```
 $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
 $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
 $table->unsignedInteger('level_id');
 $table->foreign('level_id')->references('id')->on('levels');
```

Para lo cual si revisamos en este momento la migración de la tabla `categories` ya debería existir.

Pero el error nos indica este mensaje:

> General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter tablecoursesadd constraint
>   courses_category_id_foreign
>   foreign key(category_id)
>   referencescategories(id))

Revisando la sección de comentarios indicas que el orden de tus migraciones es:

```
teacher 
students 
courses 
levels 
categories 
subcriptions 
coments 
requirements 
goals 
table_course_student 
reviews
```

Por lo cual vemos que el error esta referido a que primero creas la tabla `courses` y luego `categories` por lo tanto solucionarlo debería requerir solamente invertir y quedar como:

```
categories
courses
```

Para que de este modo cuando tu requieres la construcción de la llave foránea `category_id` y su vínculo con la tabla `categories` esta última ya exista.